# Datetimepicker is not getting applied to my class

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

My UI looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="cabname" class="border inputpicker timepicker timepicker-no-seconds readonly-cursor-allowed ml-0" readonly>'
```

I have two buttons in my UI for setting 'min' and 'max' time. If the user clicks the 'min' button the following function will be triggered:

```
function toggle_check_uncheck(element) {
  $('input[name$="cabname").addClass('.mintime');
}
```

However the `mintime` class is not being applied to my UI timer. On inspection `mintime` is attached to the UI class but it does not get applied.

```
$('#mintime').datetimepicker({
  minTime: '12:00'
});
```

It is not getting applied to my inputpicker class:

```
$(".inputpicker").datetimepicker({
  ignoreReadonly:true,
  format: 'LT',
  defaultDate: getDate() + ' 00:00'
});
```

Comment: Firstly, please take the time to format your questions so they are readable. I've done this for you in this case. Secondly, the issue is because you are most likely calling `$(".inputpicker").datetimepicker({` when the page first loads - before the element has that class. You need to also instanciate the `datetimepicker()` on the elements when you add the class to them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  thanks for the formatting, and should i use like this $('input[name$="cabname").addClass('.mintime').datetimepicker()? while adding class

Comment: Yes - that would work. Don't forget to include your settings object too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i had tried like this $('input[name$="cabname"]').addClass('.mintime').datetimepicker(minTime: '12:00' ); but it doesnt get applied, whether is this correct? as im new to this technology, could you check it once

Comment: That should work. Check the console for errors. Also, does the target element exist? If you change that line to `console.log($('input[name$="cabname"]').length)` what output do you see?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan checked the length , it returns 1, and get the error as uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list   but the braces were closed accordingly           $('input[name$="cabname"]').addClass('.mintime').datetimepicker(minTime: '12:00' );  this was i used

Comment: The problem is due to the missing `)` syntax error, but it's not the line of code you included that's causing that error - it must be somewhere else in your code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i had used like this $('input[name$="cabname"]').addClass('.mintime').datetimepicker({minTime: '12:00' }); and it doesnt throw any error, but still the minTime is not get applied in my UI..